# Error use mysql-slow.log permission

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

I've a Galera Cluster Installation with three nodes. As requirement my MariaDB installation must be in different path that default, and user cannot be `mysql`. So I've moved all mysql data path and I've created a new user and group to manage the mysql service.

MariaDB service is working fine, but I've noticed that a `mysql-slow.log` has been created with permissions to `mysql:root` for a third program installation that monitor queries. Opening `mysql.err` I've found the following error:

> [ERROR] Could not use mysql-slow.log for logging (error 13).Turning logging off for the whole duration of the MySQL server process. To turn it on again: fix the cause, shutdown the MySQL server and restart it.

So I've made `chown myuser:mygroup mysql-slow.log` and restart the service, but there still having same permissions. Then I've set in `my.cnf` the `slow_query_log=1`, in order to try that the myuser create the file at start, but the wrong permission still there also after remove the files and restart.

All the files, in my mariadb data path, are not managed by `mysql:mysql` user, in my installation are managed by `myuser:mygroup` so when the `mysql-slow.log` is created the permissions `mysql:root` are assigned so I have not permission to write there with `myuser:mygroup` and if I assign them manually there is not effect because are override with `mysql:root` after mysql restart.

Somebody knows if there are any way to set by default the user and group owners of the mysql-slow.log file when created?

Thanks.

Regards,

Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Fix the permissions:

```
chmod 666 mysql-slow.log
```

See what your script is doing; perhaps it needs fixing, too.